# Can't open SQLite database with custom bindings

Tags: android, sqlite

## The Goal

I want to implement geofencing in my app, but need to support filtering through these geofences based on their proximity to the user.

## The Approach

- Geofences are stored on a server.
- These are downloaded by a [Worker] when changed.(https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Worker)
- Selecting the nearest geofences is powered by the [SQLite R*Tree module](https://sqlite.org/rtree.html)

## Steps taken

The R*Tree module is disabled for SQLite on Android. To remedy this, you need to add your own SQLite lib to your project.

There's [multiple options](https://sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/install.wiki) to add Android Bindings to a custom SQLite lib.

The first option didn't suit my needs and adding the source code is a last resort which shouldn't resolve my current issues.
I've chosen the *second option* and enabled the R*Tree module by setting `-DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE` to 1 in `src/main/java/jni/sqlite/Android.mk`:

```
# Enable SQLite extensions.
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS5 
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DSQLITE_ENABLE_RTREE=1
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DSQLITE_ENABLE_JSON1
LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3
```

I've also performed step 3, and added the output to my project by adding the .aar to my libs folder.

### build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar','*.aar'])
  // other dependencies
}
```

### other code files

The imports have been updated and the library has been loaded, like [this document](https://sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/usage.wiki) defines.

#### Offending methods

These methods are used for interacting with a pre-existing table which is not using the R*Tree module.

```
static List<LocationInterface> getSince(SQLiteDatabase database, long millisecondsSince1970) {
    if (database == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = database.query(TABLE_NAME, null, LocationTable.COLUMN_CREATED_AT + " > " + millisecondsSince1970,
                null, null, null, LocationTable.COLUMN_CREATED_AT, QUERY_LIMIT);

        if (cursor == null || cursor.isClosed()) {
            return null;
        }

        // cursor is closed at the end of the function
        return getLocations(cursor);
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        database.close();
    }
}

static void deleteBefore(SQLiteDatabase database, long millisecondsSince1970) {
    database.delete(TABLE_NAME, LocationTable.COLUMN_CREATED_AT + " <= " + millisecondsSince1970, null);
    database.close();
}

private static List<LocationInterface> getLocations(Cursor cursor) {
    List<LocationInterface> locations = null;

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        locations = new ArrayList<>();
        do {
            if (cursor.isClosed()) {
                break;
            }

            // Creates a LocationInterface object, does not modify cursor
            locations.add(getLocationFromCursor(cursor));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    return locations;
}
```

#### Imports used

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
```

#### SQLiteOpenHelper

There's a custom implementation for SQLiteOpenHelper which is implemented using the Singleton Design Pattern.
We're using this class, which in turn uses the application context of the first caller's context, to get our readable of writeable database.

```
final class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static DatabaseHelper instance;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;

    public static synchronized DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        LocationTable.createIfRequired(db);
        GeofenceContract.createIfRequired(db);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        LocationTable.upgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        GeofenceContract.upgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

## The problem

The database cannot be opened.

### Stacktrace

```
09-05 17:45:35.575 28508-28615/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 37631 of [c7ee083322]
    (14) os_unix.c:37631: (2) open(//myDatabase.db) -
09-05 17:45:35.576 28508-28615/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database 'myDatabase.db'.
    org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:466)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:180)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:810)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:795)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:698)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:721)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:259)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
    at com.example.sdk.core.ExampleDatabase.getSince(ExampleDatabase.java:64)
    at com.example.sdk.core.LocationDispatcher.postLocations(LocationDispatcher.java:41)
    at com.example.sdk.core.DispatchWorker.sendLocations(DispatchWorker.java:74)
    at com.example.sdk.core.DispatchWorker.doWork(DispatchWorker.java:49)
    at androidx.work.Worker.onStartWork(Worker.java:70)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:195)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
09-05 17:45:35.625 28508-28615/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteOpenHelper: Couldn\'t open myDatabase.db for writing (will try read-only):
    org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:466)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:180)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:810)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:795)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:698)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:721)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:259)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
    at com.example.sdk.core.ExampleDatabase.getSince(ExampleDatabase.java:64)
    at com.example.sdk.core.LocationDispatcher.postLocations(LocationDispatcher.java:41)
    at com.example.sdk.core.DispatchWorker.sendLocations(DispatchWorker.java:74)
    at com.example.sdk.core.DispatchWorker.doWork(DispatchWorker.java:49)
    at androidx.work.Worker.onStartWork(Worker.java:70)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:195)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
09-05 17:45:35.817 28508-28615/com.example.android.demo E/DispatchWorker: No locations sentserver
09-05 17:45:35.817 28508-28615/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 37631 of [c7ee083322]
    (14) os_unix.c:37631: (2) open(//myDatabase.db) -
09-05 17:45:35.823 28508-28615/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database 'myDatabase.db'.
    org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
09-05 17:45:35.824 28508-28615/com.example.android.demo E/WorkerWrapper: Work [ id=2cc7ccee-72c9-4178-a6ce-891ef3696faa, tags={ Example_dispatch_work, com.example.sdk.core.DispatchWorker } ] failed because it threw an exception/error
    org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:466)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:188)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:180)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:810)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:795)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:698)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:721)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:259)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:199)
    at com.example.sdk.core.ExampleDatabase.deleteBefore(ExampleDatabase.java:73)
    at com.example.sdk.core.DispatchWorker.sendLocations(DispatchWorker.java:96)
    at com.example.sdk.core.DispatchWorker.doWork(DispatchWorker.java:49)
    at androidx.work.Worker.onStartWork(Worker.java:70)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.runWorker(WorkerWrapper.java:195)
    at androidx.work.impl.WorkerWrapper.run(WorkerWrapper.java:117)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
09-05 17:45:42.069 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 37631 of [c7ee083322]
    (14) os_unix.c:37631: (2) open(//myDatabase.db) -
09-05 17:45:42.121 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database 'myDatabase.db'.
    org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
09-05 17:45:42.171 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteOpenHelper: Couldn\'t open myDatabase.db for writing (will try read-only):
    org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
09-05 17:45:42.425 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/DispatchWorker: No locations sentserver
09-05 17:45:42.474 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 37631 of [c7ee083322]
    (14) os_unix.c:37631: (2) open(//myDatabase.db) -
09-05 17:45:42.475 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database 'myDatabase.db'.
    org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
09-05 17:45:42.516 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/WorkerWrapper: Work [ id=2c27be2a-94c9-4bca-a63a-34133bb7e7dd, tags={ Example_dispatch_work, com.example.sdk.core.DispatchWorker } ] failed because it threw an exception/error
    org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
09-05 17:45:43.914 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 37631 of [c7ee083322]
    (14) os_unix.c:37631: (2) open(//myDatabase.db) -
09-05 17:45:43.915 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database 'myDatabase.db'.
    org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
09-05 17:45:43.916 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteOpenHelper: Couldn\'t open myDatabase.db for writing (will try read-only):
    org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
09-05 17:45:44.063 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/DispatchWorker: No locations sentserver
09-05 17:45:44.063 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteLog: (14) cannot open file at line 37631 of [c7ee083322]
    (14) os_unix.c:37631: (2) open(//myDatabase.db) -
09-05 17:45:44.065 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/SQLiteDatabase: Failed to open database 'myDatabase.db'.
    org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
09-05 17:45:44.066 28508-28616/com.example.android.demo E/WorkerWrapper: Work [ id=d128fc77-b562-4da8-8a28-8e74d071f168, tags={ Example_dispatch_work, com.example.sdk.core.DispatchWorker } ] failed because it threw an exception/error
    org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:214)
    at org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:198)
```

## Attempted solutions

- Used `libsqliteX` for a library name to import instead of `sqliteX`
- Closed database after each operation (either a `SELECT` or `INPUT` command). Enforced via `try - finally`.
- Added `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission.
- Lots of 'clean builds'
- Recompiled the SQLite lib again.

## The Question

Am I forgetting something? What are things I need to verify and be aware of when compiling the SQLite library with custom extensions?
What is the root of my problem?

Comment: You have not show any of your code. How are you accessing your custom SQLite library?

Comment: I'm accessing it like I would use the Android lib, I'm just using other imports and avoiding Android-specific classes like `DatabaseUtils`.
I've added some detail to my question, does this help @CL.?

Comment: The directory looks wrong. What context object are you using?

Comment: The application context :/

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Comment: I was not. I'm currently testing whether I really need this optimalisation.